# Hot to write an EOF to a file, to stop any tailing processes

Tags: kill, tail

I have multiple processes tailing a file, how can I write an EOF to the file, to stop the tailing processes?

for example,

```
tail -F $HOME/somefile.log
```

that is being run in some terminal somewhere, not sure where.
How can I write an EOF to the log file, so that any process which is tailing that file, stops tailing it?

In some cases, I am tailing a fifo:

```
mkfifo fivel
tail -f fivel
```

I believe that writing an EOF to a named pipe might actually stop/kill any processes tailing the fifo, whereas writing an EOF to a regular file may not stop tailing processes.

Comment: You can't.  The only way to stop `tail -f` is to kill `tail`.

Comment: yeah, that seems to be the case, thanks for verifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this **does not** seem like the right way to achieve this.
I think you want to target the tail process[es] reading the file instead of the file itself.
Consider something like the following instead.

```
ps -ef | grep "[t]ail" | grep 'somefile.log' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs kill
```

1. `ps -ef` will display all processes running on your system.
2. `grep "[t]ail"` will will find all processes with tail in the name (excluding this grep).
3. `grep 'somefile.log'` will find from these the ones with somefile.log in the name.
4. `tr -s ' '` will squeeze all multiple spaces down to one.
5. `cut -d' ' -f2` will using space as delimiter get only the second column which is the PID.
6. `xargs kill` will kill that PID.

This will kill any tail processes reading the file (bar some strange corner cases e.g. log file called tailsomefile.log).
There may be a cleaner way of doing this but this was the first immediately obvious solution to me.
I have tested that this is working on Linux.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62155/discussion-on-answer-by-rlf-hot-to-write-an-eof-to-a-file-to-stop-any-tailing-p).

Answer (score 2):

The tail command does not exit on EOF when run with -f on a regular file.
It explicitly waits for more data. So there already is an EOF at the end of your file - it just doesn't cause tail to exit because it shouldn't do that.

The only way is to kill tail. Run

```
ps ax|grep tail
```

and then kill the process id that shows up at the fitting tail process. Alternatively use

```
pkill tail
```

to kill all tail processes. Use this with care as you might kill processes that you don't want to kill.

Comment: `tail -f` does stop on EOF when reading from a non-seekable descriptor, f.i. a pipe: `echo foo | tail -f`.  Also, `pkill tail` will kill `tail` on most modern systems.

Comment: thanks @SatōKatsura, I swear I read that an EOF can stop tailing processes, but it might just be for fifo/named pipes. I updated the question.

Comment: @AlexanderMills The entire point of `tail -f` is to ignore `EOF` on input and retry (meaning, clear the error, seek to the last position, and read again), until there's more data to read.  However this doesn't work for unseekable input.  That's why the only consistent behavior is to stop.